# Is there a way to run a command line command from JScript (not javascript) in Windows Scripting Host (WSH) cscript.exe?

Tags: command-line, command, javascript, wsh

I'm writing a JScript program which is run in cscript.exe. Is it possible to run a commnad line command from within the script. It would really make the job easy, as I can run certain commands instead of writing more code in jscript to do the same thing.

---

For example:
In order to wait for a keypress for 10 seconds, I could straight away use the timeout command

```
timeout /t 10
```

Implementing this in jscript means more work.
btw, I'm on Vista and WSH v5.7

any ideas? thanx!

Answer (score 9):

You can execute DOS commands using the [`WshShell.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) method:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run("timeout /t 10", 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true /* bWaitOnReturn */);
```

If you specifically need to pause the script execution until a key is pressed or a timeout elapsed, you could accomplish this using the [`WshShell.Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f.aspx) method (a dialog box with a timeout option):

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Popup("Click OK to continue.", 10);
```

However, this method displays a message box when running under cscript as well.

Another possible approach is described in this article: [How Can I Pause a Script and Then Resume It When a User Presses a Key on the Keyboard?](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/oct04/hey1005.mspx) In short, you can use the [`WScript.StdIn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y8934a7.aspx) property to read directly from input stream and this way wait for input. However, reading from the input stream doesn't support timeout and only returns upon the `ENTER` key press (not any key). Anyway, here's an example, just in case:

```
WScript.Echo("Press the ENTER key to continue...");

while (! WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
   WScript.StdIn.Read(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanx for the help ppl, this was my first post and stackoverflow is awesome!
Also, I figured out another way to do this thing, using the `oShell.SendKeys()` method.
Here's How:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.SendKeys("cls{enter}timeout /t 10{enter}");
```

This way you can run almost every dos command without spawning a new process or window

EDIT: Although it seems to solve the problem, this code is not very reliable. See the comments below

Comment: Your SendKeys string is incorrect - it should be "cls{enter}timeout /t 10{enter}" (without pluses).

Comment: Also, your variant is very unreliable. First of all, `SendKeys` sends keystrokes to the active window, so the input might be sent to another window that has been accidentally activated. Also, if there're commands following `SendKeys`, they won't nesessary be executed after `SendKeys`. Try inserting the `WScript.Echo` commands before and after `SendKeys` and removing `cls` from the input string -- and you will see that the script output is messed up and the `timeout` command is executed last of all.

Comment: Yeah..this code is really messy! I started experiencing problems once I ran it with the rest of the code and its true that with SendKeys, statements don't necessarily get executed as they appear.
It gets even worse if you have a WScript.StdIn.Readline() with SendKeys(), as it wouldn't wait for the user to input coz it's already getting input from SendKeys and it does break up things the nasty way!
Lesson learnt: Be very careful with SendKeys, it can be sloppy
great insight helen!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the `WScript.Shell` object.

[See the docs and samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx)