# Using JavaScript to perform OS commands?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute commands such as `/ipconfig` by double-clicking a JavaScript file on your desktop? Just like you do with VBScripts in Windows.

If not, is there any Java-based scripting file type that can handle this?

With scripting file type I mean something such as .BAT, .VBS or .PS1. Avoid .JAVA or .JAR answers as these files aren't as easy to build nor they are scripts.

Comment: you can right code in node.js and bundle node.js with electron to build portable executable

Comment: You're probably looking for JScript (not JavaScript), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441867/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-command-line-command-from-jscript-not-javascript-in-wi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly execute a javascript file.
You have to use Nodejs from a command line or somehow call nodejs to execute a particular .js file from a .bat, .exe etc file

Answer (score 0):

With a batch(.bat) file:

```
@Echo off
pause
cd\windows\system32
ipconfig /all
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 files:

File 1 - script.js:

```js
'use strict';
console.log("Hello from script!");
```

File 2 - test.js

```js
'use strict';
const cp = require('node:child_process');
const command = "node script.js"
cp.execSync(command, { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Run:

```bash
node test.js
```

Expected output:

> "Hello from script!"